# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Suppose you have two calendars:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" />
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" />
```

Suppose you click on May 16, 2013 in both and do the following:

```
Calendar2.SelectedDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate.AddDays(1);
Calendar2.SelectedDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate.AddSeconds(-1);
```

If you display the values of

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

you get

```
05/16/2013 12:00:00 AM
05/16/2013 11:59:59 PM
```

respectively. Now, here is the problem: if you write the following C# LINQ-to-SQL query:

```
var dates = from   d in Database
            where  d.Date >= Calendar1.SelectedDate &&
                   d.Date <= Calendar2.SelectedDate
            select d;
```

`dates` will not select entries even if they exist for this day. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

However, if I do this:

```
var dates = from   d in Database
            where  d.Date >= Calendar1.SelectedDate &&
                   d.Date <  Calendar2.SelectedDate.AddDays(1)
            select d;
```

it will work. What is going on!?

Comment: Did you try to do all this and get the list result like dates.ToList() in one method?

Comment: `Database` is just a table where I keep a bunch of random dates.

Comment: Please do share the dates from your table (it helps for testing)

Comment: If the database type is `date` and not `datetime` then the time-of-day data is lost, making the comparison null. What is the SQL generated by EF being sent to your database server?

Comment: `d.Date` in `Database` is of type `DateTime`.